# How to check if the connections between points are crossing each other?

Tags: graph, geometry, coordinates, time-complexity

Lets consider the following problem:

We have a 4 Points `{a,b,c,d}` and want to check if the 
ways `[a;b]` and `[c;d]` would cross each other if we connect the 
points by lines on a paper.

The point is defined as `(x|y)` so it can be drawn into a 2-dimensional 
coordinate system.

How can I check this in `O(1)`?

Comment: the c++ is irrelevant. this is basic geometry: http://www.wikihow.com/Algebraically-Find-the-Intersection-of-Two-Lines

Comment: @Marc B, the question was about two line **segments** not two lines.  So getting the answer from the link you posted would be beyond the math skills of many programmers.  The answer is much more obvious in this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28Euclidean_geometry%29#Two_line_segments

Answer (score 2):

There is effective method to check whether two line segment intersect:
AB and CD intersect, if C and D points lie in different semi-planes relative to AB line, and C and D lie in different semi-planes relative to CD line. [Here is](http://bryceboe.com/2006/10/23/line-segment-intersection-algorithm/) concise Python implementation:

```
def ccw(A,B,C):
    return (C.y-A.y)*(B.x-A.x) > (B.y-A.y)*(C.x-A.x)

def intersect(A,B,C,D):
        return ccw(A,C,D) != ccw(B,C,D) and ccw(A,B,C) != ccw(A,B,D)
```

Thorough treatment of special cases (collinearity, coincidence) [is described here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/)

Comment: This is quite another question. Gavin's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1968345/844416 gives good practical implementaion of intersection point calculation